# Gram-Schmidt algorithm to find orthonormal basis

Tags: functional-analysis

I must use the Gram-Schmidt algorithm to find an orthonormal basis for Sp$\{1,x,x^2 \}$ in $L^2[-1,1]$.

Suppose the elements of the orthonormal basis are $e_1, e_2$ and $e_3$. Then they must be pairwise orthogonal and $\|e_i \|=1$ for each $i$.

I thought of trying with the standard inner product $<f,g>=\int_X \mid f \bar{g} \mid d\mu$ on $L^2$, where $ X=[-1,1]$. However I have no idea of how to determine the orthogonal basis.

Comment: First, you should not have to choose your inner product. It should be defined by the problem. Since you say $L^2$, you're using this inner product: $$\int f\overline{g}dx.$$ Note that there aren't any absolute values. That said, the algorithm will automatically spit out orthonormal vectors if done right. At what point in executing the algorithm did you get stuck?

Comment: Okay, thanks!
I found $e_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and I'm confused about what to do to find $e_2$.

Comment: So once you find $e_1$, you want to project $x$ onto it to get some vector $p$. Then take $x - p$. This new vector will automatically be orthogonal to $e_1$, since $(x-p,e_1) = (x,e_1) - (p,e_1) = 0$, by definition of $p$. Normalize it to get $e_2$. Now project $x^2$ onto the span of $e_1, e_2$, subtract, and normalize again.

Comment: Modulo scaling, these are the Legendre polynomials, of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Gram-Schmidt's ortogonalization process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) for a description.

You get (note that everything is real, so you don't have to worry about complex conjugates)
\begin{align}
u_2 &= v_2 - \operatorname{proj}_{e_1} v_2 \\
    &= v_2 - \langle e_1,v_2 \rangle e_1 \\
    &= x - \left( \int_{-1}^1 x \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \,dx\right) = x
\end{align}
and
$$
e_2 = \frac1{\|v_2\|}v_2 = \left( \int_{-1}^1 x^2\,dx \right)^{-1/2} x = \frac{x\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}.$$

I'll leave the computation of $e_3$ to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mrf, I've been able to get $e_3$ as per the answer.